# How to abort Jenkins build from shell script?

Tags: jenkins

I see that returning a non-zero integer in shell script executing on Jenkins will make the result marked as a failure.

How do I make it change to *Aborted*? Is there a plugin to do this? Can I avoid having to use GroovyScript?

Comment: When do you want to changed to `Abort` ? when shell scripts failure, strange behavior. It is tricky to be done without groovy.

Comment: Yeah I'd love to use Groovy but this shell command must be executed on a remote SSH. Being that the SSH will receive the exit output and interpret it. Unless there's a remote groovy interpreter..

Comment: Please clarify your request (when to abort) and give sample bash script inside (ssh remote execution). The groovy script is done in postbuildtask plugin mostly.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of returning a non-zero integer and having the build fail, you could trigger an Abort on the build using its Rest API within the shell build step.

Example using curl:

```
curl -XPOST $BUILD_URL/stop
```

Example using wget:

```
wget --post-data="" $BUILD_URL/stop
```

Comment: I've recently had to implement this and the solution provided by @clipitar was the way to go. One important thing: if CSRF is enabled – which is the default for a Jenkins install – make sure you read the ‘CSRF Protection’ section here https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API for details about obtaining a crumb. This will be needed in the actual “/stop” POST request, alongside the authentication headers.